# Is there a way to "force" an app in OS X to have a menu bar icon?

Tags: osx-lion

Fluid makes menubar "apps" out of webpages etc, but i just want to stick a "launch" icon in the menu bar for, let's say screen sharing. Can it be done? is there an app out there that does that?

I want the opposite of of what DockDodger does, which hides icons from the dock when running. I want "MenuPutter".

Answer (score 0):

If the app itself isn't programmed to provide a menu bar icon, then no, you can't really do that. You would have to program that yourself, I guess.

The only alternative that comes to mind is [aLaunch](http://mactips-lib.net/m/software/alaunch/en/main.html), which allows you to put various applications into your menu bar for easy access:

[image]

Comment: It's *aLunch*. Om nom nom.

Comment: Huh. Good spot. You should file a bug report :P

Answer (score 0):

I have used in the past [XMenu](http://www.devontechnologies.com/products/freeware.html%20%3Cbr%3E) (freeware) by devonTechnologies. (Scroll down to the bottom left of the page). 
I'm not sure if 'aLaunch' is limited to only one menu or not, but

XMenu can have a up to 6 menus in the menubar.